# Capture the same pixel rectangle at different resolutions

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to capture the same pixel rectangle area no matter what the resolution of the currently selected monitor is. I have some code that captures the areas I need at (1920x1080, 2560x1440) but I am currently hard coding the start/end points of the area I need. I know there's a much better way of doing this as my current way is sloppy and works for only two resolutions. Any recommendations on a approach?

```
If Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Height = "1080" Then
    StartX = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Left + TenStartX
    EndX = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Left - StartX + TenEndX
    StartY = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Bottom - TenStartY
    EndY = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Bottom - StartY - TenEndY
ElseIf Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Height = "1440" Then
    StartX = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Left + FourteenStartX
    EndX = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Left - StartX + FourteenEndX
    StartY = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Bottom - FourteenStartY
    EndY = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Bottom - StartY - FourteenEndY
End If
        Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim graph As Graphics
        Dim bounds As New Rectangle(StartX, StartY, EndX, EndY)

        screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
        graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
        graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

        Return New Bitmap(screenshot)
```

Called with:

```
Test.Image = GetImage(48, 210, 53, 35, 63, 220, 70, 47)
```

As you can see the correct pixel start and end points vary slightly depending on the resolution. I also need to expand this to be able to work on any resolution. I'm stumped ;/

Comment: The most logical way to do this is to use a size ratio that can be calculated as needed and without _any_ hardcoding.  You would choose a 'standard' size, and then modify the rectangle on the X and Y axis by the ratio of the current screen to your `standard` screen on each of them.

Comment: Wouldn't i need to also modify the rectangle size itself, along with the x/y axis of it? Different resolutions would adjust the size of the area i need to capture, so the rectangle would have to grow/shrink also to capture exactly what i need.

Comment: It depends on exactly how your area is laid out on differing resolutions.  Typically, the ratio of the area would be identical on all display sizes (i.e. it's always 20px from all edges, or it always occupies 80% of the width and 60% of the height).  Perhaps if you could illustrate the problem further?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is capture the same section of a image, no matter what resolution the monitor that the image is being displayed on is. The example i posted above gives me the results i need for a 1080p/1440p monitor, how can i alter that to not have hard coded pixel points, and not be limited to only two resolutions?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/umfZu7N.png
For example, i want to capture "Button" no matter what resolution it's being displayed on.

Comment: on 1080p, i get the correct image: https://i.imgur.com/sBOyOMO.png
. On 1440p, it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/dBCHhED.png

How would i edit the below code so the 1440p captures the same as 1080p.
            Dim posX As Long = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Left + 48
            Dim posY As Long = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Bottom - 65

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, now just need to figure out the math to adjusting the rectangle to shrink/grow also.

```
        Dim OCoordx = "65"
        Dim OCoordy = "1369"

        Dim posX As Long = OCoordx / 2560 * Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Width
        Dim posY As Long = OCoordy / 1440 * Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Height

        posX = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Left + posX
        posY = Screen.AllScreens(intMonitorSelected).Bounds.Top + posY
```